# Class '\Omnipay\Gkash\Gateway' not found

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, omnipay

I was trying to implement the gkash payment gateway in laravel project v5.8 but face some issues here, the issues is like

```
local.ERROR: Class '\Omnipay\Gkash\Gateway' not found {"userId":"61efa2c1a4876ad729519ac1","exception":"[object] (Omnipay\\Common\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Class '\\Omnipay\\Gkash\\Gateway' not found at /var/www/thenewnoms.com/vendor/omnipay/common/src/Common/GatewayFactory.php:85)
[stacktrace]
```

does anyone have face this issue before ? All the class name, namespace is correct, works fine in local, but when it show this error when at live. Anyone can help me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you install the package as Dev dependecy?

Comment: Make sure to run composer install so that all the dependencies are available for usage.

Comment: run `composer install` and `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: you should use the class in above of the document

Comment: @Bulent yea, I have did that

Comment: @AmirKhaledian  yes, the name is all the same

Comment: @Vishal I have did that also

Comment: @TipuSultanEiko yea, this is the solutions, I have cleared the cache then run composer install again

Comment: Thanks all and sorry for the late reply

Comment: Dev-dependencies work only in production mode.

Comment: sometimes problem is about case sensetive. check out package names and every thing about your package and  your class for case sensetive